# How to lock Data Base when pg_restore runs

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-restore, backup-sqldatabase

When running pg_restore we encounter some (unexpected) executions from some other programs resulting in errors in the restoration.

Is there a way to lock the DB while restoring to insure no modifications are done ?

This is the command executed :

```
pg_restore --clean --verbose --no-owner /home/postgres/backup/bkp --if-exists -j 7 -d restdb01 -p 5432
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- revoke connect permissions from the database or reject connections in `pg_hba.conf` (remember that by default, `PUBLIC` can connect to the database)
- use `pg_terminate_backend` to cancel all existing connections
- run `pg_restore` as a user that can still connect to the database

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL documentation of [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgrestore.html) does not provide any info of such functionality.

According to [wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_database) postgresql does not support database locking.

I suggest using permission mechanism to prevent anyone connecting to the database beeing restored:

1. Create a new database.
2. Grant CONNECT permission to that database to a single user used in pg_restore command (--username=db-admin).
3. Restore.
4. Add all the required permissions to the database.

Unless you have applications connecting to your server as superusers, that will prevent applications from reading or changing